# Creating a server that responds to requests on subtract

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server, subtraction

The server should respond to requests on '/subtract', accepting two parameters, 'a' and 'b', and returning the difference between them as a plain text response.

I have tried to create the server and include the request.

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/subtract', function (req, res) {
  res.send(String(Number(req.query.a) - Number(req.query.b)));
});

app.listen(8080);
module.exports = app.listen(8080);
```

I expect:
'/subtract?a=2&b=3.4' should return -1.4

Comment: And what is happening? does it return other number? or anything at all? is there an error?

Comment: if it did not return -1.4, what did it return then? your question is incomplete.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Questions which ask for debugging help need to tell us what's wrong.

Comment: Error: Cannot GET / subtract

Answer (score 2):

Your code works for me you just need to remove this line `module.exports = app.listen(8080);` you cannot listen twice on the same port!

> [image]

Did you install `express`?

Comment: Did you install `express` and did you start it with `node your_file.js`, is another server using this port?

Comment: I had an issue with terminal, its all sorted now. Thanks